# Make bigdelim work with non-paragraph columns

Tags: bigdelim

In one of my tables I'd like a brace to extend over multiple rows.  Elsewhere on TeX.SE the `bigdelim` package is recommended for this purpose.  However, it doesn't seem to work for `tabular` columns not using the `p` format specifier.  For example, the first of the following tables looks correct, with the brace extending across three rows, whereas the brace in the second table is the same height as the "foo" text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{2em}l}
  \ldelim\{{3}{*}[foo] & bar \\
                       & baz \\
                       & quux \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \ldelim\{{3}{*}[foo] & bar \\
                       & baz \\
                       & quux \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of above document]

Am I doing something wrong or is this an undocumented limitation of the `bigdelim` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you specify a width for `\ldelim`. You do not have this restriction if you use  `blkarray`, which provides the same functionality:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2em}l}
  \ldelim\{{3}{*}[foo] & bar \\
                       & baz \\
                       & quux \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \ldelim\{{3}{2em}[foo] & bar \\
                         & baz \\
                         & quux \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{blockarray}{\Left{foo}{\{\,}l}
  bar \\
  baz \\
  quux \\
  Lalala…\\
\end{blockarray}
\hskip2cm\begin{blockarray}{l}
\begin{block}{\Left{foo}{\{\,}l}
  bar \\
  baz \\
  quux \\
\end{block}
Lalala…\\
\end{blockarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]